# IE7 not loading eot webfont

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, font-face, webfonts, eot

I'm having issues with a custom icon font pack in IE7. It's not loading at all. It works great in IE8+, FF and Chrome. IE8 also uses eot, so it's not an issue with the font file itself.

In IE7 mode of IE11 on the Network tab shows that there is no request at all to the eot file (but it has in IE8 mode, and also tried native IE7 on a virtual machine).

I've tried Fiddler also to check if there is a request but nothing.

I'm using the following code to embed the font:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Icons";
  src: url("./Icons.eot");
  src: url("./Icons.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("./Icons.woff") format("woff"),
       url("./Icons.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("./Icons.svg#Icons") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I also tried to concentrate only on IE7 so i removed those and used only this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Icons";
  src: url("./Icons.eot");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Still no success, Fiddler still not seeing any request to the file.

I'm using an Nginx server, added the following MIME Type for eot files: `application/vnd.ms-fontobject`

Also even if it's not a cross-domain request, i added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` just for sure.

Any clues why there is no even request at all?

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5946221/3448527)

Comment: Thanks, but also tried :) But i have it working now.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to go the "FontAwesome way". I've created a separate IE7 stylesheet with CSS expression.

```
.icon-caret-down {
    font-family: "Icons";
    *zoom: expression( this.runtimeStyle['zoom'] = '1', this.innerHTML = '&#xf104;');
    font-style: normal;
}
```